# spark streaming reduceByWindow, need mean, median, max, std, IQR

Tags: python, apache-spark, mapreduce, spark-streaming

I am sending data to spark streaming(Python) using TCP sockets.

Using windowed streaming of windowLength = 4 seconds and slideInterval = 2 seconds
My RDD in one window section looks like below :

```
[1,2,3,4]    
[2,2,2,2]    
[5,6,7,8]    
[1,2,1,1]    
[8,7,6,5]
```

How can I find the mean, median, max, std, IQR of the 'corresponding' values.
mean = [(1+2+5+1+8)/5 , (2,2,6,2,7)/5 ,(3+2+7+1+6)/5 ,(4+2+8+1+5)/5 ]

So far for mean my code is :

```
def importData():
    sc = SparkContext(appName="test1")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2)
    RowsData = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)
    RowsData = RowsData.map(lambda x: x.split(","))
    RowsDataLIST = RowsData.map(lambda mylist: [int(strTono) for 
    strTono in mylist])
    print("Print the Rows Data List with windows 4,1")


    RowsDataLIST = RowsDataLIST.window(4,2)
    TheMean = RowsDataLIST.reduce(lambda x, y: list(map(np.mean,zip(x,y))))

    TheMean.pprint()

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()


def main():
    importData()
if __name__ == "__main__":  
    main()
```

And the output for mean is [1.0, 0.75, 4.0, 2.25], which is obviously wrong. I understand for .reduce(lambda x, y: ...), it is taking two rows at a time and taking the mean. However, if I need mean for all the corresponding elements in the RDD within window, what should be the approach.

- One way I can take the sum and divide by the count. But was wondering there is a different way.
- Also, how can I approach to calculate different statistics of corresponding elements of the lists.

I am new to spark streaming, please guide.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?